# In LDAP: Differentiating via OU or via attribute?

Tags: attributes, ldap, posix, sssd

I am using LDAP to allow access to a Linux system.  The users and groups are structured as follows:

- Groups and users are represented via `posixGroup` and `posixUser`, respectively.
- Each group corresponds to a research group.
- Each research group has a leader.
- The leader of a group may or may not be a user.

I would like to do the following:

- Set the `owner` attribute of each group to DN of the group leader.
- Prevent the owner from having access unless also a user.

What is the best way to distinguish between users and owners?  I see two possibilities:

1. Use two OUs: `ou=users` and `ou=leaders`.  Leaders who are also users would appear in both groups.
2. (Mis-)Use an attribute: `employeeType` can take multiple values, e.g `user`, `leader`, or `user,leader`.

It seems that approach 1 would be easier to configure in `sssd`, but are there other pros and cons of the two approaches?

Comment: "The leader of a group may or may not be a user": OK, *why?* This is the root of your problem. What is the reason for it?

Comment: That's just the way it is.  I need know who the group leader is, so I can contact that person if a user in the group, say, does not respond. However, rather than having an `ou=leaders` I am currently tending towards having a `groupOfMembers` as `cn=leaders` and then adding `member` attributes like `uid=xyz`, where `xyz` is the UID of a leader. Actual users would then all go in `ou=users`.

Comment: Additionally, a leader may also become a user, but will still remain also a leader.